# How to adjust column width of exported excel file using ngx-export-as in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, export, angular8, export-to-excel, xlsx

I am using [ngx-export-as](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-export-as) library to export table data into excel file,
but after exporting data it shows **default** column width in the downloaded excel file and even though the column title is long such as "**Expired Quantity**" it doesn't shows column width auto-expanded or fit to that title length.

Can anyone suggest me how to increase column width before we export file in such case?